# Failed to import bridging header FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-login

I am trying to add the Facebook login using Parse with swift and I have been following the iOS Developers guide. However it states swift compiler error: failed to import bridging header FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found and the issue was found in the Test section on Xcode. Please can someone please help me to rectify this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this exact problem by actually copying the Facebook desired frameworks (in my case CoreKit, LoginKit and ShareKit) from the ~/Documents/FacebookSDK folder to the project folder.

To achieve that, I just dragged the frameworks into the project folder on XCode, but I CHECKED the option "Copy items if needed".

After that, everything worked in the first build.

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.7 and XCode 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I CHECKED the option "Copy items if needed" and build succeeded.

works for XCode 7.1 , Facebook SDK 4.7.1